# css div inside div position

Tags: css, css-float, html

I have a div main container that contained 3 others div containers.

I want that the 3 child div stay center and always on the same height (at the top of the parent div).

My problem is when I resize the window browser, the child div go under the other. I don't want this.

I also add a css condition for under 768px. In this case, I want that the child div go under the others.

Here a fiddle example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/mCXWs/

In this fiddle the child the blue div go under the green and the yellow under the blue for a window browser above 768px. I don't want this result. I want the stay at the same height (top: 0;)

I don't know what to do ...

Sorry for English, I'm French

Answer (score 0):

- 3 blocks always of the same height? Use **CSS** table layout: `display: table` and `display: table-cell` (IE8+)
- a (block displayed as a) "cell" will never go below another "cell", problem already solved (edit: in the same implicit row)
- centered horizontally? Use `margin: 0 auto;` on container
- at the top of parent div? Use `vertical-align: top`.
- under 768px (in MQ @-rule), just override `table(-cell)` by `display: block` and divs will behave like default div, going one under another. You also have to override min/max-height, maybe.
- avoid `overflow: hidden` and `position: relative` (well, with tables...) as long as you can

Working example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/EEEjg/1/

Comment: thanks a lot! It works great! How can I center the child div under 768px? I update the fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/EEEjg/2/. Does the 768px correspond to the main container (portfolio-content)

Comment: Still with `margin: 0 auto` (on each 3 elements to be centered).

Comment: Beware that in your MQ, `margin-top: 65px` is overriden by `margin: 0 auto;` in the same rule

Comment: I try to put some text inside a one of the child div but the text container don't want to be responsive... http://fiddle.jshell.net/EEEjg/5/

Comment: That's a different question. In short, you're using aboslute positioning so it's removed from the flow, will be displayed above other things, won't push the container down, etc: it's like it wasn't there. Do not use position: something for layout except if you exactly know what you're doing. Stick with floats, inline-block  and maybe table layout made in CSS (for same height blocks)

Comment: I tried to add an other width condition for under 1040px. I want to put the yellow container under the others but I don't success to do it..How can I put a div under the other with table-cell? http://fiddle.jshell.net/EEEjg/7/